# Can Scala classes be used in Java?

Tags: java, scala

```
class Wish{
    val s = "Hello! User.  Wish you a Great day."
}

object Wish{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val w = new Wish()
        println("Value - " + w.s )
   }
}
```

Java classes can be used in Scala.  Similarly,  can Scala classes be used in Java?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Scala classes can be called from Java and vice versa.

The below text is taken from: [Scala FAQs](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4)

> What does it mean that Scala is compatible with Java?
>
> The standard Scala backend is a Java VM. Scala classes are Java classes, and vice versa. You can call the methods of either language from methods in the other one. You can extend Java classes in Scala, and vice versa. The main limitation is that some Scala features do not have equivalents in Java, for example traits.

The following post also could be helpful to you: [how to call Scala from Java](http://blog.muhuk.com/2016/05/24/how_to_call_scala_from_java__using_scala_classes.html#.WWGyrtPytTY)

Comment: no example how to play with objects

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you want to do this, there are a few things you might want to remember:

- Do not use operators in your method names or provide a wordy alternative. Operator names can be called from Java but are mangled into somethings very ugly.
- Java users might expect Java style getters and setters. You can produce those automatically by adding `@BeanProperty` annotation to fields.
- In the same way Java user might be accustomed to factory methods called `ClassName.of` where Scala uses `.apply`. Those you have to provide by hand, if you want to provide that service.

Comment: no code example